# Edit protected windows registry keys

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I'm developing an application to help streamline the windows experience.

It disables cortana, ads, telemetry, turns off taskbar grouping, hidden folders and extensions etc.
It does this through registry keys.

It appears that Microsoft does no longer allows the editing of protected keys.
A concrete example: Trying to create the key `DisableAntiSpyware` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender` results in the following error:

> "The Registry Editor cannot rename New Value#1. Error while renaming
>   value."

Unfortunately I wasn't able to create the key - not even by hand and not even after altering permissions.

This seems to be a recent issus as the application was working just fine on previous versions/updates of Windows 10.

So, if you have any idea how to edit protected key, please let me know. I'm aware there are workaround to my particular example (through group policy) but I'd like to know if this issue can be fixed. Thank you!

Comment: I can't reproduce this using regedit. Is your app running in admin mode? And why aren't you creating it with the right name from the beginning? Is it possible that the anti-virus took control here?

Comment: It may be possible to change it using Windows external media

Comment: You could try running the Registry Editor with system privileges.
This can be done by using the tool PsExec.
It can be downloaded from the Microsoft website.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec
The command to run the registry editor with system privileges is:
psexec -s -i regedit.exe
You should at least be able to change the value manually using psexec.
You could then try to fix the permissions while running regedit as system.